# "[os_mon] cpu supervisor port (cpu_sup)" error while starting Tsung test

Tags: erlang, cpu-usage, tsung

I'm the newbie in performance testing with Tsung, so maybe my question seems obvious to someone, but...

I have installed the Tsung on Mac (OS X 10.11.2) which already has Erlang using homebrew:

[Erlang and Tsung versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrM8A.png)

Next, I have created very simple tsung.xml file:

```
<clients>
    <client host="localhost" use_controller_vm="true" maxusers="10" cpu="4" />
</clients>

<servers>
    <server host="google.com.ua" port="80" type="tcp" />
</servers>

<load>
    <arrivalphase phase="1" duration="10" unit="second">
        <users interarrival="10" unit="second" />
    </arrivalphase>
    <arrivalphase phase="2" duration="2" unit="minute"></arrivalphase>
</load>

<sessions>
    <session name='MainPage' weight='50' type='ts_http'>
        <request>
            <http url='/' version='1.1' method='GET' />
        </request>
    </session>
</sessions>
```

And uploaded it to the right folder (/Users/User_Name/.tsung). After that I started test using `tsung start` and got an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcITb.png):

> Last login: Fri Jan 22 16:54:37 on ttys000
>   macpro15:~$ tsung start
>   Starting Tsung
>   Log directory is: /Users/User_Name/.tsung/log/20160122-1821
>   Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
>   [os_mon] cpu supervisor port (cpu_sup): Erlang has closed

Can anybody tell me what I have done wrong?

P.S. I have tried to run this test on the PC with Linux Ubuntu and new versions of Erlang/Tsung (downloaded from off. sites and compiled from sources) but I got the same error.

Comment: The problem is most likely related to the "permission denied" error you're getting, and the `cpu_mon` message is probably just a side effect of the process dying from that error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Steve.
I tried to run the test with `sudo` but I got the same error, so I suppose that the problem not in permissions.

Comment: `sudo` isn't going to help here. The permissions error has to do with authentication; the error says that publickey authentication failed, and then keyboard-interactive authentication also failed. My guess is that you either don't have a public key set up, or permissions on your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file are incorrect (they should be 0600).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot do ssh to your localhost. First create a ssh public key using this command:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

Then copy the key to the authorized keys:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```